# Google api redirect uri issue while using google drive V3 api in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using google drive API to upload file to drive.I am using OAuth2 with "**application type : Other**". Everything works fine on localhost while running code and files are uploaded as expected. In local development environment, browser returns a Google concent screen for allowing different permissions to api and once clicked on "**Allow**" button, the file gets uploaded as expected to drive. But when this working code is published on IIS server , it gives "**502:Bad Gateway**".

[image]

After debugging I found that below line of code is returning error.

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                 Scopes,
                "my email id",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

I think the Google consent window to allow permission is failing to open on IIS Server. How to solve this issue? Please suggest.

Also When I try to access API using "**application type : web application**", it gives me an error **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch** on localhost itself.

[image]

I tried many options with redirect uri like **http://localhost:62283** , **http://localhost:62283/Home/Index.cshtml** , **http://localhost:62283/Home** etc , tried changing the 62283 to some other port also , but still no luck. 
Also the error showing "**http://127.0.0.1:63562/authorize/**" , I am unable to understand how and from where its referring this "127.0.0.1:63562 address and port automatically. Searching for solution from last week. I am unable to understand what redirect uri should I provide? Any suggestions or ideas to solve this error?

Comment: `To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit` - did you try this?

Comment: yes I tried it.It redirects me to google api client key.